# Can the Mobile Management facility of Google Apps For Business be used to control which apps are installed from Google Play?

Tags: google-play-store, google-apps, multiple-devices

Am considering buying Google Apps For Business to improve management of a large number of Android devices.

We will provide an app that we have created to our users through our private channel. We do not want users to install any other apps unless we have authorised them.

For example, we may wish users to have WhatsApp but not Flappy Bird 2.

Can the Mobile Management facility of Google Apps For Business be used to control which apps are installed from Google Play?

Comment: Am not 100% sure where you're coming from, but Google Apps is free and on majority of Android devices, unless you're talking about some enterprisey version of Google Apps for business usage - might be better to deal directly with Google about this... Even am not sure if this is a valid question as it seems to govern corporate usage of the google channels which may be outside of scope for here... unless another AE user would give their opinion on this?

Comment: Please see edited question. I mean Google Apps For Business

Comment: Ok, fair enough :) Its a business enterprisey version you're referring to, as I have stated in my comment, you need to talk to Google themselves to find out if that can be done... :)

Comment: I think this question is perfectly on-topic for the site, but as @t0mm13b points out, I don't think our regular users have experience with Google Apps for Business. Since this is an easy pre-sales question, Google should be able to give you an answer. Please post it here when they do, to help future visitors!